# Implementing a birthday reminder via cron job and php mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I've read through other questions regarding cron jobs which run through php queries, but the error I'm getting seems syntax-specific and I'm hoping someone can help. (I'm new at all this and teaching myself, so dumb mistake potential is high).

I'm trying to set up a cron job which runs once per day. Its job is to query a list of users in a mysql database that lives on the same server, determine if any of them have a birthday on that day and echo the response for the cron job to email to me.

Here is the database creation code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test ( sid INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, birthday DATE );
insert into test values(NULL,'Jane Doe','2022-5-17');
insert into test values(NULL,'John Doe','2022-5-20');
```

Here's my php file (birthdayChecker.php):

```
<?php 
$conn = new mysqli('server', 'username', 'password', 'schema');
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die('Connection failed: ' . $conn->connect_error);
}
$result = $conn->query('select Name from test where MONTH(Birthday)=MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) and DAYOFMONTH(Birthday)=DAYOFMONTH(CURRENT_DATE)');
foreach ($result as $birthday)
{
    echo 'Heads up: ' . $birthday['Name'] . ' has a birthday today!';
}
```

I'm not totally sure how to share the cron setup, but it's setup to run once every ten minutes right now. I know it's running, because I'm getting the emails, but this is what they say:

```
fullpath/birthdayChecker.php: line 1: ?php: No such file or directory
fullpath/birthdayChecker.php: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
fullpath/birthdayChecker.php: line 2: `$conn = new mysqli('server', 'username', 'password', 'schema');'
```

especially given that line 1 error, I'm pretty sure I'm just doing something stupid, but I can't see it. Appreciate any help!

Comment: You might have an invisible character before or near the `<?php`. Delete that whole line, hit backspace a few more times for good measure, then retype it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - I tried it, but it was not the issue.

Comment: What is the exact line in your cron for this file?

Comment: This turned out to be the problem - I needed to tell it to use php.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be that I needed to tell the cron job to use php (the shell knows, but cron doesn't apparently):

```
php -f fullpath/birthdayChecker.php
```

it also took a little more fiddling with the actual php code to get it to cooperate:

```
$query = "select Name from test where MONTH(Birthday)=MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) and DAYOFMONTH(Birthday)=DAYOFMONTH(CURRENT_DATE)";
$result = $conn->query($query)->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

foreach($result as $row)
{
  echo "Heads up: " . $row["Name"] . " has a birthday today!";
}
```